# Probability of Geometric Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following question and I'm having a hard time following the answer:

> Let $X \sim Geo(p)$ and $Y \sim Geo(q)$ be independent random variables.  Compute $P(X<Y)$.

$P(X<Y) = P(Y=m)P(X=n)$

\begin{align}&(1) \qquad P(X<Y) = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}P(Y=m)P(X=n)\\
&(2) \qquad P(X<Y) = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}(1-q)^{m-1}q\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(1-p)^{n-1}p\\
&(3) \qquad P(X<Y) = q\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left[(1-q)^{m-1} - [(1-q)(1-p)]^{m-1}\right]\\
&(4) \qquad P(X<Y) = 1 - \frac{q}{1-(1-q)(1-p)} = \frac{p - pq}{p+q-pq}\end{align}

In step $(3)$, what happened to $p$?  Overall, how did they go from step $(2)$ to step $(3)$?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Apply change of variables $u=n-1$ to the last term of item $2$ and use $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{r} x^{k} = \frac{x^{r+1}-1}{x-1}$ by considering $x=1-p$ and $r=m-2$.

Update:

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1} q \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (1-p)^{n-1}p &= q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1} \displaystyle \sum_{u=0}^{m-2} (1-p)^{u}p \\
&=q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1} p \displaystyle \sum_{u=0}^{m-2} (1-p)^{u} \\
&=q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1}  p \cdot \frac{(1-p)^{m-1}-1}{1-p-1} \\
& =q  \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1} p \cdot \frac{(1-p)^{m-1}-1}{-p} \\
& = q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} (1-q)^{m-1} \cdot (1-(1-p)^{m-1}) \\
& = q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \left( (1-q)^{m-1} - (1-q)^{m-1}(1-p)^{m-1}\right))  \\
& = q \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \left( (1-q)^{m-1} - ((1-q)(1-p))^{m-1}\right) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Still having problems. When I make the substitutions above and use the formula I get:

$\frac{x^{m-1}-1}{x+1}p = \frac{(1-p)^{m-1}-1}{(1-p)+1}p = \frac{(1-p)^{m-1}-1}{2-p}p$

I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake and just can't see it.

Comment: Sorry, the formula had a typo - denominator should be x-1. I've added more details, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much.  With the new formula I see it.